# Crear bucle de borrado de ficheros y directorios JAVA

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente código para borrar ficheros y directorios si llevan más de 2 días sin modificar. El caso es que sólo me borra en 2 capas de directorios y necesito que lo haga desde la ruta dada, sin importar cuántos directorios anidados haya.

```
public class Borrado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        File directorio = new File("C:" + File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "PAS" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "borrar");
        //Obtener fecha actual
        Date fechaActual = new Date();
        File[] ficheros = directorio.listFiles();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
            
            if(ficheros[i].isDirectory()) {
                String ruta = ficheros[i].getAbsolutePath();
                borrarDirectorio(ruta);
            }
            System.out.println(ficheros[i]);
            // Obtener fecha de modificación del fichero 
              long ms = ficheros[i].lastModified();
              Date fechaModif = new Date(ms);

              //Diferencia en dias entre las dos fechas
              int dias=(int) ((fechaActual.getTime()-fechaModif.getTime())/86400000);

              // si la fecha de modificacion es anterior a dos días respecto a la fecha actual entonces borramos el fichero 
              if (dias > 2) {
                 ficheros[i].delete();
                 
              }
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void borrarDirectorio(String ruta) {
        File subDirectorio = new File(ruta);
        Date fechaActual = new Date();
        File[] subFicheros = subDirectorio.listFiles();
        
        for(int j = 0; j < subFicheros.length; j++) {
            
            System.out.println(subFicheros[j]);
            // Obtener fecha de modificación del fichero 
              long ms = subFicheros[j].lastModified();
              Date fechaModif = new Date(ms);

              //Diferencia en dias entre las dos fechas
              int dias=(int) ((fechaActual.getTime()-fechaModif.getTime())/86400000);

              // si la fecha de modificacion es anterior a dos días respecto a la fecha actual entonces borramos el fichero 
              if (dias > 2) {
                  subFicheros[j].delete();
                  subDirectorio.delete();
              }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Pues sin ver tu código, va a ser complicado poder responderte qué estás haciendo mal. Publica un ejemplo claro de lo que tienes hecho y vemos...

Comment: Lo puse en un comentario, nunca había utilizado esta página...

Comment: Hola @nixis el método normal es editar tu pregunta y añadir la información.

Comment: Voy a probar @nax Gracias!!

Comment: El problema es que cuando llamas a la función borrarDirectorio ya no tienes en cuenta que en ese directorio haya más directorios. Te recomiendo que pruebes con una función recursiva, entrando en todos los directorios hasta que no haya más, borrando y volviendo hacia atrás borrando todo.

Comment: Por cierto oracle tiene un tutorial muy detallado sobre esto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html en ingles eso si

Comment: Gracias, miraré cómo hacer la función recursiva y el tutorial de oracle.

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-delete-directory) tienes un ejemplo de función recursiva muy sencilla.